# PowerMock whenNew, thenReturn equivalent in Mockito and JUnit5

Tags: java, testing, mockito, junit5, powermock

We are migrating from `PowerMock` and `JUnit` 4 to `Mockito` and `JUnit5`. I have a very simple setup class.

```java
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    service = new ExpressProcessorService<>(prefs);
    
    //whenNew(ExpressCreditCardClient.class).withArguments(prefs).thenReturn(expressClient);
    MockedConstruction<ExpressCreditCardClient> mockedExpressCreditCardClient = mockConstruction(ExpressCreditCardClient.class);

    }
```

I know about inline mock dependency and already have it and I have seen a few answers in so that I unfortunately did not understand.

Could somebody explain what exactly the commented whenNew line does, and how to do the exact same in `Junit5` + `Mockito`?

Comment: What exactly is prefs?

Comment: Just an argument passed to the constructor. Does it matter?

Comment: @malevolence109 How have you resolved the same ? Trying to understand same, for a similar situation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a field in your test class, such as:

```
ExpressCreditCardClient expressClient = ...creation of mock...
```

or

```
@Mock
ExpressCreditCardClient expressClient
```

**Regarding powermockito code that you shared:**

> whenNew(ExpressCreditCardClient.class).withArguments(prefs).thenReturn(expressClient);

Shortly, what it does is: stub specific constructor of `ExpressCreditCardClient` class with certain argument value passed.

If `ExpressCreditCardClient` class is instantiated through a constructor that takes a single argument, and that argument is equal to `prefs`, then instead of executing actual code it will return a mocked instance of the `ExpressCreditCardClient` class (the `expressClient`).

**Regarding junit5/mockito approach:**

```
MockedConstruction<ExpressCreditCardClient> mockedExpressCreditCardClient = mockConstruction(ExpressCreditCardClient.class);
```

This one mocks any constructor with any argument values passed.